# MLE of a function involving absolute values

Tags: statistics

I have some pdf $f(x|\theta) = (\theta/2) ^ {|x|} \cdot (1 - \theta) ^ {(1 - |x|)}$
where $x = -1, 0, 1$, and $0 \le \theta \le 1$.

I am tasked with finding the MLE of theta. The way I see it there are two cases, x = -1, 1, and x = 0. I get MLEs of 1 and 0 respectively once I simplify the pdf and find the maximum given the constraints on theta. I'm not sure if this is correct though since I don't know much about MLEs being constant.

Could somebody take a peek at this and let me know if I'm going the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

The $x$'s are supposed to be your data. It is not clear whether you have a sample of size $3$, or you have a larger sample, where there are some $x=-1$, some $x=0$, some $x=1$. Assume this more general case. Denote $n_{-1}$ the number of realizations where $x=-1$, $n_{0}$ the number of realizations where $x=0$ and $n_{1}$ the number of realizations where $x=1$. $n=n_{-1}+n_{0}+n_{1}$ is the size of the sample. Then, under the assumption that these are independent random variables, the joint density of the sample is

$$f(X\mid \theta) = \Big[(\theta/2) ^ {|-1|} \cdot (1 - \theta) ^ {(1 - |-1|)}\Big]^{n_{-1}}\cdot \Big[(\theta/2) ^ {|0|} \cdot (1 - \theta) ^ {(1 - |0|)}\Big]^{n_{0}} \cdot \Big[(\theta/2) ^ {|1|} \cdot (1 - \theta) ^ {(1 - |1|)}\Big]^{n_{1}}$$

$$=(\theta/2) ^ {n_{-1}}  \cdot (1 - \theta) ^ {n_{0}} \cdot (\theta/2) ^ {n_{1}} = (\theta/2) ^ {n-n_{0}} \cdot (1 - \theta) ^ {n_{0}}$$
and the log-likelihood

$$\ln L =  c+ (n-n_{0})\ln \theta + n_{0}\ln (1-\theta)$$

Calculating now the MLE of $\theta$ is straightforward.